# Where should I put a medication effectiveness in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir

Our practitioners go back after a med admin and chart the effectiveness of the medication.  Right now I am putting this as an event in the admin event history.  Is this correct?

Part of me thinks this is an observation, but then that gets away from the medication admin object that it's referring to.

Just curious to get another perspective.

Thanks!

Also, I am working in FHIR 3.

Answer (score 1):

It's not something that's supported in core for MedicationAdministration, though you could capture it as an extension.  Given it's something asserted after-the-fact and it's something where different people could potentially have different opinions at different times, a separate Observation would make sense.  Though, at the moment, you'd need to use an extension to link the Observation to the administration event.  (You might consider proposing a change request to generalize the list of Observation.related resources to "any" and add an appropriate relationship type - say "focus" or "assesses" or something.)

Comment: I put in a change request: 12580  To have a list of observations added to either the MedAdmin object or to the MedOrder object